# Jquery UI dialog, only opens once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I realize this has been asked before, but I am unable to get this to work even after reading other answers.

I'm using Jquery UI basic dialog popup to open a pop-up for a set of images.

However, I am only able to open an image once, then the dialog will not open again. 
Here is my code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> // added .dialog:disaplay:none; to desktop.css
        $(".open").click(function(BasicDialog) {
            var div = $(this).next("div.dialog");
            var dia = $(div).dialog({
                draggable: false,

                width: "300px",
                modal: true,
                title: "",
                buttons: {
                    "Close": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");

                    }
                }

            });
            BasicDialog.preventDefault();
        });
</script>
```

Can anybody give me a hint towards what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: When you have problems like this it is helpful to provide a link to JSFiddle with your code : http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

autoOpen property. It is what you are looking for. See the documentation: http://api.jqueryui.com/1.9/dialog/#option-autoOpen